# Al comparar un nombre con un usuario da error

Tags: java, array

```
for(int i = 0; i<bbdd.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j<usuario.length();j++) {
            if(bbdd[i][0].charAt(cont)==usuario.charAt(cont)) {
            cont++;

            }else {
                resul = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

bbdd es un nombre que yo he introducido en una Array de dos dimensión la columna 1 sería para las contraseñas.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 4

Comment: *`IndexOutOfBoundsException`*  ocurre cuanto intentas acceder a un índice superior a la cantidad de elementos que hay en un array. Depura tus objetos `bbdd` y `usuario` para ver qué dimensiones tienen, porque al parecer los bucles anidados que estás usando sobrepasa los índices en alguno de esos elementos. Tampoco se te puede ayudar mucho porque ni siquiera se sabe lo que hace tu código... por qué se intentan leer esos dos objetos de una forma relacionada usando bucles anidados sin ningún tipo de control, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para lo que quieres hacer hay una forma mucho más sencilla, que es usando el método equals() para comprar objetos, en vez de ir letra por letra. Por otro lado es una array de dos dimensiones e iteras por su longitud, pero como comparas palabras carácter por carácter tu array puede tener un size de 3 y tu palabra tener 5 carácteres y te dará esa excepción.

```
for(int i = 0; i<bbdd.lenght(); i++){

  if(bddd[i][0].equals(usuario))
    return true;
  else 
    return false
}
```

Espero que pueda servirte de ayuda.

Un Saludo!